how to mock redis in golang
i've been use redismock in golang (github.com/go-redis/redismock/v8),
I have case for generate otp, and the otp will stored in the redis
like this "call to cmd '[set 0888888888 4980 ex 300]", are there any solution like testify has mock.Anything, but how in redismock, i need to auto argument mock in redismock to match the actual value, thank you
This is the line code for my unit test
suite.mockRedis.ExpectSet(repotest.DummyUser.PhoneNumber, "otp", ttl).SetVal("otp")
This is where the otp generated and stored to redis
otp, err := a.generateAndSendOTPTelegram(c, user.TelegramId)
err = a.Client.StoreOTPInRedis(*user, otp)
i want to match the actual otp, because its generated and not constant, i need some like mock.Anything from testify in redismock, any solution?

"because its generated and not constant" Perhaps instead of a random generator, for the tests, you can use a predictable generator. That way you can ensure that you know what value will be inserted, and as such, something like ExpectSet() can validate your code sets the right value.

(1) In my opinion, you can utilize miniredis https://github.com/alicebob/miniredis
You can make the mock redis through miniredis and make data into it.
And you can test it by using your client code.
Although redis mock is a good tool, miniredis can be more convenient because we can manipulate the mock redis as it is like a real redis.
(2) And you can test the randomness by fixing the random seed. It can help you predict your random result and use it at the test code.
Example
package __06_2

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "github.com/alicebob/miniredis/v2"
    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
)

func TestSomethingRandom(t *testing.T) {

    // 1. Set the mock redis and random string data with fixed seed.
    // the string data with fixed seed can be predicted.
    // or the data can be used at assert.Equal, right away in the test code.
    s := miniredis.RunT(t)
    randomOtp := randomStringWithFixedSeed(10, 1)
    _ = s.Set("otp", randomOtp)

    // 2. Set the client for accessing the mock redis.
    rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     s.Addr(),
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
    })

    // 3. Accessing the data from the mock redis.
    var ctx = context.Background()
    val, err := rdb.Get(ctx, "otp").Result()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("key", val)
    assert.Equal(t, val, randomOtp)
}

Output
=== RUN   TestSomething
key XVlBzgbaiC
--- PASS: TestSomething (0.00s)
PASS



OP their question appears to boil down to "my code stores a value with randomly generated data in Redis, how can I test this". Can you update your example to show that / explain why miniredis supports this where redismock doesn't?

@JoryGeerts You're right. I missed the point. Thanks for your comment. He seems lost in finding a way to control the randomness. I enhance my answer. Please check it. (Let me try to have excuses:sweat:I thought he struggled with redismock and so miniredis can be helpful, considering the title how to mock redis in golang)
